# How to jump to a file's nth character in Unix less

Tags: shell, less-unix

I have a decode error parsing a JSON file, all I am given is the location of the faulty character in the file: `char 5960`. My file has multiple lines.

How can I jump to that nth character (or at least to the corresponding line) using `less`?

---

Note: I think `vi` is able to do it, and so is `Emacs` with command repetition, but I usually use `less` so I would prefer that solution as more straighforward.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259777/how-to-move-to-the-nth-offset-in-a-file

Comment: Less cannot do such a thing.

Comment: Use `dd` to remove the first n characters and pipe to `less`

Comment: Start viewing with `less`, then press `v` to go to `vi`, then type `5960go`.